# What is difference between meet in the middle attack and man in the middle attack?

Tags: diffie-hellman, man-in-the-middle, meet-in-the-middle-attack

From my understanding man-in-the middle attack works as follow:
Alice   and Bob agreed  to  use Diffie-Hellman  using   $a$ and    $q$.   Alice sends $Y_A$.   Before  it  reaches Bob,
Charlie intercepts  it  and sends   $Y_{C1}$ instead.    Bob    believes    to  have    agreed  on  a   key $K_B$ with   Alice,  but 
the key is  actually    only    shared  by  Bob and Charlie since   $K_B = a^{X_{C1}X_B} \mod q$.

Bob sends   back    $Y_B$, and   it  is  again   intercepted by  Charlie.    Charlie sends   $Y_{C2}$ instead,   and Alice   sees    that    Bob has replied.    Alice   believes    to  have    agreed  on  a   key $K_A$ with   bob,    but they    key is  actually    only    shared  by  Alice   and Charlie since   $K_A = a^{X_{C1}X_A} \mod q$.

So how does meet-in-the middle attack compare to this example?

Comment: It's a completely different attack in a completely different scenario. There's not really anything to compare, IMO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are completely different things:

- **Man-in-the-middle** is an *active attack to a cryptographic protocol*, where the attacker is, effectively, in between the communications of two users, and is capable of intercepting, relying, and (possibly) altering messages. In this case, the meaning of "in the middle" is direct: the attacker is in the middle of two communicating users.
- **Meet-in-the-middle** is a type of *cryptanalytic attack* that uses some sort of time-space trade-off to drastically reduce the effort to perform a brute-force attack (e.g., transforming an attack that requires $2^{128}$ time into one that takes $2^{64}$ time and $2^{64}$ space). In this case, the name of the attack comes from the expression "let's meet in the middle", which means "to make a compromise". It may also refer to a type of attack over certain block ciphers, where the attacker decompose the problem in two halves and proceeds on each part separately.

The biggest difference between these attacks is that the first one is interactive (i.e., the attacker must participate in the communication), while the second one isn't.

The confusion may come from the fact that certain protocols could receive both type of attacks. For example, in your question you are talking about the Diffie-Hellman key exchange:

- A Man-in-the-middle attack to this protocol is exactly the one you describe
- A Meet-in-the-middle attack focus on extracting a private key by finding the discrete logarithm using some time-space trade-off (e.g., [baby-step giant-step algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step))

Comment: I don't think that meet-in-the-middle necessarily involves a space-time trade-off. For example collision finding or computing ECDLP require little memory yet are a meet-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: "halving the effort" is misleading as well. Typically it reduces the effort to the square-root of the original effort, halving the strength of the encryption in bits (which  scaled like the logarithm of the effort).

Comment: Thx, I will refine the answer.

Comment: Thx @cygnusv, that made things very clear

Comment: I think the name of meet-ITM just comes from solving the problem from both ends and, well, meeting in the middle.

Comment: This is a great answer. I think  `Meet-in-the-middle` is more related to `cryptanalysis` and  whereas `Man-in-the-middle` is more related to attack on some protocol. `Meet-in-the-middle` requires to resolve a hard mathematical problem.